# why is event.getMessage().getContentDisplay() not returning anything?

Tags: java, maven, discord, bots

`    package com.ahwak;

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class DiscordBot extends ListenerAdapter {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event)
{
System.out.println("We have received a message from " + event.getAuthor().getName() + ": " +    event.getMessage()
        .getContentDisplay());
if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!ping")){
    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Pong!").queue();
}
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {

    JDA bot = JDABuilder.createDefault("TOKEN")
            .setActivity(Activity.playing("Working on this bot")).build();
    bot.addEventListener(new DiscordBot());

}

 }`
```

It is supposed to return Pong! when !ping is typed but it is not working. It works correctly when I enter a message however the message does not get displayed. Meaning it outputs "We have received a message from Rexstech:    ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you have the Message Content Intent enabled in your Bot settings (in the Discord Portal):

[image]

And you also want to enable the Intent in your code:

```java
JDA bot = JDABuilder.createDefault("TOKEN")
            .setActivity(Activity.playing("Working on this bot"))
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT).build();
```

[Link to JDA Docs](https://jda.wiki/using-jda/gateway-intents-and-member-cache-policy/)

As you can read in [this article](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ) of Discord, you can see that you need to enable the Message Content Intent to receive the content of messages.